# 'Invalid date' in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date:

`let date = "15:00";`

and I want to process it to format: `2019-09-26T15:00:00.000Z`, but momentjs get and invalid date error.

I tried using `moment(date).format('LTS');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let date = "15:00"
let m = moment(date, "HH:mm");
m.utc().format();
```

Note: This will use current date's date as default since you're only passing the time.

Comment: Btw, please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Stackoverflower take their time out to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the format of value also, like this:

```
let date = "15:00";

let m = moment(date, 'HH:mm').toISOString();
console.log(m);
```

Because you need something like this `2019-09-26T15:00:00.000Z`, it's better to use the `toISOString` function, rather than the `format`.